# Efficient suffix array algorithm in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, suffix-array

Does anyone have any suggestions about where I can find a C# implementation for suffix arrays?  I'd prefer not to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: I'll doubt you'll have to reinvent the wheel just to get it in C#.  Though you may need to reimplement the wheel.

Comment: @Neil - LOL! Good point though.

Comment: https://github.com/eranmeir/Sufa-Suffix-Array-Csharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [sary](http://sary.sourceforge.net/)?  I haven't used it but it looks relevant

Comment: -1 sary is a C project, not C#.

Comment: @Eugene, it's okay. I couldn't find any c# implementations, so this was a good start.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but here is another one: [sais](http://sites.google.com/site/yuta256/SAIS-CSharp.zip?attredirects=0)